# fancybox not shown properly and closes with overlay click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using fancybox (http://fancyapps.com) in my application. I have a div defined like this:

```
 <div id="dialog-user-login" title="User Login" style="display: none" class="popup-dv">
            <div id="myDivID7">
                <div class="up-content">
                    Your Contents SHow HERE
                    <input id="txtUserName" name="txtUserName" class="normal" type="text" /><br />
                    <input id="txtpassword" name="txtUserName" class="normal" type="password" /><br />
                </div>
                <div class="social-icons">
                    <img src="wp-content/themes/touch/images/twit-icon.png" width="65" height="22">
                    <img src="wp-content/themes/touch/images/face-icon.png" width="65" height="22">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have included these files:

```
<script src="../../Content/FancyBox/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../../Content/FancyBox/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Content/FancyBox/jquery.fancybox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and using this code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $("a#fancyBoxLink1").click();

});
```

1) It shows the fancybox but when i click overlay, it closes.
2). If I use following code, it doesn't work:

```
 $("a#fancyBoxLink1").fancybox({
            'href': '#myDivID1',
            'titleShow': false,
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic'
        });
```

with this html:

```
<a href="#myDivID1" class="mrgn-ao" id="fancyBoxLink1">
        <div id="dialog-user-login" title="User Login" style="display: none" class="popup-dv">
            <div id="myDivID7">
                <div class="up-content">
                    Your Contenssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssst SHow HERE
                    <input id="txtUserName" name="txtUserName" class="normal" type="text" /><br />
                    <input id="txtpassword" name="txtUserName" class="normal" type="password" /><br />
                </div>
                <div class="social-icons">
                    <img src="wp-content/themes/touch/images/twit-icon.png" width="65" height="22">
                    <img src="wp-content/themes/touch/images/face-icon.png" width="65" height="22">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </a>
```

Please suggest me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: you are targeting `myDivID1` in the `href` attribute AND in the `href` option inside fancybox but such `selector` doesn't exist in your html code but `myDivID7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add in the `<head>` code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#fancyBoxLink1").fancybox({
'titleShow': false,
'transitionIn': 'elastic',
'transitionOut': 'elastic'
});
});
</script>
```

On the `<body>` code:

```
<a href="#dialog-user-login" class="mrgn-ao" id="fancyBoxLink1">
<div id="dialog-user-login" title="User Login" style="display: none;width:500px;" class="popup-dv">
<div id="myDivID7">
<div class="up-content">
Your Contenssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssst SHow HERE
<input id="txtUserName" name="txtUserName" class="normal" type="text" /><br />
<input id="txtpassword" name="txtUserName" class="normal" type="password" /><br />
</div>
<div class="social-icons">
<img src="wp-content/themes/touch/images/twit-icon.png" width="65" height="22">
<img src="wp-content/themes/touch/images/face-icon.png" width="65" height="22">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

href - this is the link of pop-up-div